# building dcmtk using msvc2010, unresolved external symbols (globals defined in the library)

Tags: c++, dcmtk

I am building dcmtk 3.6.3 using msvc2010 into a single dll and I used the lib to link to my program, and the globals defined in the library all reports unresolved external symbol. 
I checked both the dll and lib file using dumpbin tool and found that these globals are actually exported. The functions exported are fine to get linked.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

This is dumpbin out on one variable from the dcmtk.lib file

```
?EC_Normal@@3UOFConditionConst@@B (struct OFConditionConst const EC_Normal)
```

This is dumpbin out on one variable from the dcmtk.dll file

```
6913 1B00 008F31A0 ?EC_Normal@@3UOFConditionConst@@B
```

This is the msvs2010 error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct OFConditionConst const EC_Normal" (?EC_Normal@@3UOFConditionConst@@B)
```

In the library, .h file is:

```
extern DCMTK_OFSTD_EXPORT const OFConditionConst EC_Normal;
#define makeOFConditionConst(name, module, code, status, text) \
  const OFConditionConst name = { (module), (code), (status), (text) }
```

In the .cc file is:

```
makeOFConditionConst(EC_Normal,                        0,  0, OF_ok,      "Normal");
```

Comment: Seems you project tries to use the `dll` instead of the `lib`.

Comment: Yes, I am using dll.